# TYPO3 tt_news genericmarkers url for every news item on list view

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I create the genericmarker (###GENERIC_URL###) of "current" url and display it on single view page.

```
plugin.tt_news {
  genericmarkers.URL = TEXT
  genericmarkers.URL {
    data = getIndpEnv:TYPO3_REQUEST_URL
    wrap = link: |
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the tt_news url for every news item and display it on list view as a additional url link?

Comment: What is your problem in detail? Do you need help with the TypoScript or does your generic marker not show up/ doesn't get filled?

Comment: That code display the url of CURRENT page - so in the list item I only have the address of (current) list view page - and should be the address to single view page. In this case I need a help with TypoScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need single view url ?
This should work :

```
plugin.tt_news.genericmarkers.URL = COA
plugin.tt_news.genericmarkers.URL {
    1 = TEXT
    1.data = TSFE:baseUrl
    2 = TEXT
    2 {
        value = 
        typolink = 1
        typolink {
            # Change 1 to page UID where your single view plugin is placed
            parameter = 1
            additionalParams = &tx_ttnews[tt_news]={field:uid}
            additionalParams.insertData = 1
            returnLast = url
        }
    }
}
```